# Algorithm to solve unfinished equations in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to write a program that when given unfinished equations will output the lowest digit that will work or -1 if none will work. I have all my input set up but at this stage I am not sure how to continue.

Example inputs are: `1+1=?`, `123*45?=5?088`, `-5?*-1=5`, `19--45=5?`, `??*??=302?`

Any tips on how to tackle this would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Runes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int caseNo = sc.nextInt();
        for (int c = 0; c < caseNo; c++) {

            String input = sc.next();
            String re1="([-]?[0-9?]+)"; // -int1 or int1
            String re2="([+\\-*])";     //+ or - or *
            String re3="([-]?[0-9?]+)"; // -int2 or int2
            String re4="(=)";                   // Equals
            String re5="([-]?[0-9?]+)"; // -int3 or int3

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

            if (matcher.find()) {

                String int1 = matcher.group(1);
                String op1 = matcher.group(2);
                String int2 = matcher.group(3);
                String op2 = matcher.group(4);
                String int3 = matcher.group(5);
                System.out.println(int1 + " " + op1 + " " + int2 + " " + op2 + " " + int3);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In a given equation, must all the `?`s be replace with the _same_ digit?

Comment: No but they are all characters between 0-9.

Comment: Does it *have* to be *Java*??

Comment: Not your example but the final product will be.

Comment: First, you need a method that checks whether or not a valid equation exists and that the answer is correct.  Taking your simplest example, you input the split values of 1 + 1 = 2 and the output would be true.  Once you have that method (and it's not trivial), then you can recurse through the digits 0 - 9 for each question mark you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to create your Java application.

1. Create an Integer index array with a value for each question mark.  In other words, if there are 5 question marks, your Integer index array has 5 elements.
2. Loop through the Integer index array.  In other words, for 5 question marks, the values ought to be (see layout below).
3. Looping through the Integer index array, substitute the index values for the question marks.
4. Check to see if the string is a valid equation.  If so, save it in a List.
5. When the looping is finished, print the List values.

Here's the layout for point 2.

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1, 0, 0, 0, 0
...
9, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 1, 0, 0, 0
...
9, 9, 9, 9, 9
```

I used your input examples to create this output.  I added spaces to the equations to make them easier to read.  I manually formatted this output to fit on the screen

```
1 + 1 = ?  -->  1 + 1 = 2
123 * 45? = 5?088  -->  123 * 456 = 56088
-5? * -1 = 5  -->  No equation exists
19 - -45 = 5?  -->  No equation exists
?? * ?? = 302?  -->  57 * 53 = 3021     53 * 57 = 3021     72 * 42 = 3024     
                     42 * 72 = 3024     48 * 63 = 3024     56 * 54 = 3024     
                     36 * 84 = 3024     84 * 36 = 3024     54 * 56 = 3024     
                     63 * 48 = 3024     55 * 55 = 3025     89 * 34 = 3026     
                     34 * 89 = 3026
```